# Derivative Of A Lagrangian

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In a proof about the necessary condtion for a given function $q(t) \text{  s.t }q(t_1)=a, q(t_2)=b $

$$S(q)=\int_a^b \mathcal{L}(q,\dot{q},t) $$

To be minimize (For all $p(t)$  s.t  $p(t_1)=p(t_2)=0$ , $S(q+p)\geq S(q)$)

I have the following statement: Let $p(t) = \varepsilon h(t)$ for some $h(t)$ if $\mathcal{L}$ if differentiable then:
$$\mathcal{L}(\alpha(\varepsilon),\beta(\varepsilon),t)=\mathcal{L}(\alpha(0),\beta(0),t)+\varepsilon\frac{d \mathcal{L}}{d\varepsilon}+o(\varepsilon)=\mathcal{L}(\alpha(0),\beta(0),t)+\varepsilon\frac{d \mathcal{L}}{d\alpha}\frac{d \alpha}{d\alpha}++\varepsilon\frac{d \mathcal{L}}{d\beta}\frac{d \beta}{d\beta}+o(\varepsilon)$$

I understand the second equality as it is a total derivative, but how we arrive to the first equality and where did $\alpha(\varepsilon),\beta(\varepsilon)$ came from?

Comment: Looks like a taylor expansion as $\varepsilon=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is confusing because you're introducing different variables without defining them; but it seems like you're trying to derive the condition for the action integral defined by $S$ to be stationary (also your limits of integration seem to be wrong). Like you, I am also confused about what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are because they haven't been defined anywhere. But generally, here's what you do:

Let $h:[t_1, t_2] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a "nice" function such that it vanishes at the endpoints. What you want to compute is the directional derivative of $S$ at $q$, in the direction of $h$, and set that equal to $0$. In other words, you're defining a new function $F : I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is a small open interval containing $0$, by the rule
\begin{equation}
F(\varepsilon) = S(q + \varepsilon h),
\end{equation}
and you want to impose the condition $F'(0) = 0$. (If you do this for every function $h$, then intuitively, this is like requiring that $S$ doesn't change much in any direction, as long as the "displacement" from $q$ is small) The computation of $F'(0)$ runs as follows:
\begin{align}
F'(0) := \dfrac{d}{d\varepsilon} \bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q(t)+ \varepsilon h(t), q'(t) + \varepsilon h'(t), t)
\end{align}
First, we can move the derivative inside the integral and make it a partial derivative by Leibniz's Integral rule. Next, for simplicity of notation, denote $\alpha_t = (q(t), q'(t), t)$; also, let $\partial_1L(\alpha_t)$ mean the partial derivative of $L$ wrt the first entry evaluated at $\alpha_t$; usually you see the notation $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q}(\alpha_t)$, and you see $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q'}(\alpha_t)$ instead of $\partial_2L(\alpha_t)$. With this, once we move the derivative inside, we use the multivariable chain rule to get:
\begin{align}
F'(0) &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left[ \partial_1L(\alpha_t) \cdot h(t) + \partial_2L(\alpha_t) \cdot h'(t) \right] \, dt \\
&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left[\partial_1L(\alpha_t) - \dfrac{d}{dt}\left( \partial_2L(\alpha_t) \right) \right] \cdot h(t)\, dt  + 
\bigg[ \partial_2L(\alpha_t) \cdot h(t) \bigg]_{t_1}^{t_2} \\
&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left[\partial_1L(\alpha_t) - \dfrac{d}{dt}\left( \partial_2L(\alpha_t) \right) \right] \cdot h(t)\, dt
\end{align}
where in the second equal sign, I integrated by parts and in the third line, I used the boundary conditions on $h$.

---

This is usually the outline of how the Euler Lagrange equations are derived (they are certainly necessary conditions for the curve $q$ to be a stationary point of the action $S$). Also, there are many subtleties which I glossed over, so I'd highly recommend reading a book on the Calculus of Variations; for example the excellent book by Henri Cartan, titled [Differential Forms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486450104) has a section which carefully treats this subject.